# Newline appears after <br> tag in DOMDocument saveHTML()

Tags: php, html, dom, domdocument

I'm using the PHP DOM API to create some markup. It works OK, but a newline `\n` appears after `<br>` tags in certain cases. I managed to create a [reprex](https://repl.it/@dodov/savehtml-newline):

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTML('<div>text<br></div>');
$element = $document->getElementsByTagName('div')->item(0);

echo $document->saveHTML($element); // newline appears after <br>
```

For some reason, `saveHTML()` doesn't return the same markup that was initially loaded. As I've demonstrated in the repl, adding text around the `<br>` tag or using `saveXML()` works correctly.

Is this some special behavior defined in the [DOM spec](https://www.w3.org/DOM/DOMTR)? The problem only appears to happen when the `<br>` tag is the first or last child, I.E. there's no text in between.

Comment: `loadHTML` and `saveHTML` don't follow the DOM Spec as they will allow mangled XML which most people call HTML. Your example has an unclosed `<br>` tag and yet still reads it.  There are various other things it will kindly do for you which may not be really what you want, but it works for some very badly formed HTML.

Comment: Take a look at [formatting Output](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php#domdocument.props.formatoutput)

Comment: @NigelRen according to the [HTML spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/single-page.html#start-tags), `<br>` is a void element and putting `/` before its `>` has no effect and is therefore optional? No one said PHP follows that spec, though.

@MarkusZeller I tried setting `formatOutput` to `false`. Same thing happens. I think `false` is the default value, though.

Comment: @NigelRen also, even if I have `<br/>` instead of `<br>`, `saveHTML()` still adds `\n` and outputs the tag as `<br>` anyways.

Comment: The problem is that DOMDocument is an XML library not a HTML library.  It has it's own rules about how it thinks HTML should be fixed and output.  The newline as no effect on HTML and so it probably doesn't see it as an issue.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to have been a bug in [libxml](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.libxml.php). The problem occurred in version 2.9.7, but after updating to XAMPP 3.2.4 with PHP 7.3.8 and libxml 2.9.9, the problem ceased to exist.